# Make column not nullable in a Laravel migration

Tags: php, sql, database-migration, laravel

I'm writing a migration to make certain columns in a table `nullable` right now. For the down function, I of course want to make those columns `not nullable` again. I looked through the [schema builder docs](http://laravel.com/docs/database/schema), but couldn't see a way to do this.

Comment: the most complete answer for this question can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32568625/4908847

Answer (score 341, accepted):

Prior to Laravel 5, there was no Laravel native way of altering an existing table column using the schema builder. You'd need to use raw queries for this.

However, as of Laravel 5 you can use:

```
$table->string('foo')->nullable(false)->change();
```

You must have the dbal dependency prior to running the above command:

```
composer require doctrine/dbal
```

Comment: That's what I found as well. A nice touch would for the schema builder to allow for altering column definitions, which it does not seem to support. I'm sure there are many others like myself who are using the schema builder to modify an existing DB, not just creating tables from scratch.

Comment: Taylor Otwell (creator of Laravel) said 6 days ago (2014-05-09): "I still stand by my statement that if anyone can successfully and cleanly do it I will merge it." https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/895#issuecomment-42709756

Comment: Actually now you can do it in laravel 5:  http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/schema#changing-columns

Comment: @Musa Apparently you can set a column nullable (ex: `$table->string('colmn', 255)->nullable()->change();`) but the reverse doesn't appear to work (`$table->string('colmn', 255)->change();`), so you still need to use raw db queries for this

Comment: I've found a more explicit answer and some guidelines [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24425013/1498118)

Comment: See @MattMcDonald's answer below.  You can use nullable() to make it nullable and nullable(false) to make it Not nullable in a migration.

Comment: `nullable(false)` doesn't work for me in Laravel 5.3 :(

Comment: This works, however, I had an INT column which was unsigned. When I tried to remove nullable, it also tried to remove unsigned. OTOH, it wouldn't remove nullable when I left out `nullable()` instead of doing `nullable(false)` explicitly. I'm a bit worried about that because it seems self-contradictory. At least I got it with this `$table->integer('foo')->unsigned()->nullable(false)->change()`

Comment: @aross Use `unsignedInteger('foo')` for an unsigned integer shorthand.

Comment: @MattMcDonald If I was codegolfing I would care about the 4 bytes saved, but thanks anyway :)

Comment: nullable(false) doesn't work for me in Laravel 5.6 on a string column

Comment: Required first `composer require doctrine/dbal`

Answer (score 53):

As of Laravel 5 it's possible to reverse this by passing false as an argument to `nullable`.

```
$table->string('foo')->nullable(false)->change();
```

Comment: It works! So this has become the correct answer because of updates to Laravel.

Comment: Thanks, although I don't understand why columns aren't made non-nullable by default. It's usually best practice and this adds lots of noise to the code.

Comment: Columns are non-null by default. The poster was just asking how to reverse an already null column.

Comment: Required first `composer require doctrine/dbal`

Answer (score 13):

First run this:

`composer require doctrine/dbal`

Then create a migration that will alter the table like so:

`php artisan make:migration fix_whatever_table_name_here`

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('table_name', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->type('column')->nullable(false)->change();
    });
}

# Optional:
# public function down()
# {
#     Schema::table('table_name', function ($table) {
#         $table->type('column')->nullable()->change();
#     });
# }
```

Comment: Is there a reason to drop the entire column in the rollback routine? The down() method should just undo the up() method's logic to support rolling migrations backward and forward.

Answer (score 10):

You can just declare the column again without ->nullable() and use ->change

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('table_name', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->type('column')->nullable(false)->change();
    });
}

public function down()
{
    Schema::table('table_name', function ($table) {
        $table->type('column')->nullable()->change();
    });
}
```

Comment: thanks, it works for me. my case was inverse. I want to make the column not nullable in the down function.

Answer (score 0):

In laravel 8, you just have to put this:
"->nullable()"

```
$table->string('name')->nullable();
```