# Laravel Migration Change to Make a Column Nullable

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, nullable, laravel-migrations

I created a migration with unsigned `user_id`. How can I edit `user_id` in a new migration to also make it `nullable()`?

```
Schema::create('throttle', function(Blueprint $table)
{
    $table->increments('id');
    // this needs to also be nullable, how should the next migration be?
    $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
}
```

Answer (score 427):

Laravel 5 now supports changing a column; here's an example from the offical documentation:

```php
Schema::table('users', function($table)
{
    $table->string('name', 50)->nullable()->change();
});
```

Source: http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/schema#changing-columns

Laravel 4 does not support modifying columns, so you'll need use another technique such as writing a raw SQL command. For example:

```php
// getting Laravel App Instance
$app = app();

// getting laravel main version
$laravelVer = explode('.',$app::VERSION);

switch ($laravelVer[0]) {

    // Laravel 4
    case('4'):

        DB::statement('ALTER TABLE `pro_categories_langs` MODIFY `name` VARCHAR(100) NULL;');
        break;

    // Laravel 5, or Laravel 6
    default:                

        Schema::table('pro_categories_langs', function(Blueprint $t) {
            $t->string('name', 100)->nullable()->change();
        });               

}
```

Comment: Thx for this. But how can I make the opposite? How to change a column to not be nullable? Any ideas?

Comment: @algorhythm Do you try this ' $t->string('name', 100)->change();'

Comment: @MURATSPLAT No, I did it with `DB::statement` and raw SQL... But maybe I'll try it later... Thx

Comment: You need to require doctrine\dbal to migrate

Comment: @algorhythm `->nullable(false)` will let you change the column back again.

Comment: ->change() requires you to install the Doctrine DBAL package, and it does not inherently recognize all the same column types that are available out of the box from laravel.. for example double is not a recognized column type to DBAL.

Comment: It would not work if you try to rename column in the same function, you need to run 2 functions on the same table to perform rename and changing.

Comment: @MURATSPLAT: I have same problem and while I add the doctrine/dbal dependency to my composer.json file, `change` method isn't recognized and don't work.I install Laravel 5.7.

Comment: Hello @sarina 
I have looked up official Laravel doc  and I can see there is no change. Did you read it ? https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/migrations#modifying-columns

What is the error if the method is not working..

Comment: @MURATSPLAT. Hi. My problem solved. I should write edited column in a new migration file and migrate it but I migrate previous migration file.

Answer (score 233):

Note that this is only possible in Laravel 5+.

First of all you'll need the **doctrine/dbal** package:

```
composer require doctrine/dbal
```

Now in your migration you can do this to make the column nullable:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        // change() tells the Schema builder that we are altering a table
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->nullable()->change();
    });
}
```

You may be wondering how to revert this operation. Sadly this syntax is not supported:

```
// Sadly does not work :'(
$table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->change();
```

This is the correct syntax to revert the migration:

```
$table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->nullable(false)->change();
```

Or, if you prefer, you can write a raw query:

```
public function down()
{
    /* Make user_id un-nullable */
    DB::statement('UPDATE `users` SET `user_id` = 0 WHERE `user_id` IS NULL;');
    DB::statement('ALTER TABLE `users` MODIFY `user_id` INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL;');
}
```

Comment: This is the most complete answer for L5, but it should be mentioned that if 'user_id' is a foreign key, which it should be, you won't be able to change it unless you run 'DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0');' first. And set it back to 1 when you're done.

Comment: Thank you, `nullable(false)` saved me from pulling my hair out, because `nullable()` is not well documented, and there is no `notNull()` function.

Comment: this doesn't work for foreign keys with postgres. trying `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0` gives an error. you will likely need to alter the table's constraints by using a raw query. see here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-altertable.html

Comment: This is breaking my tests. The tests start to run and then hang. I suppose the first rollback causes this. Causes hanging tests for MySQL as well as for SQLite.

Comment: doctrine/dbal isn't required if use raw queries

Answer (score 166):

I assume that you're trying to edit a column that you have already added data on, so dropping column and adding again as a nullable column is not possible without losing data. We'll `alter` the existing column.

However, Laravel's schema builder does not support modifying columns other than renaming the column.
So you will need to run raw queries to do them, like this:

```
function up()
{
    DB::statement('ALTER TABLE `throttle` MODIFY `user_id` INTEGER UNSIGNED NULL;');
}
```

And to make sure you can still rollback your migration, we'll do the `down()` as well.

```
function down()
{
    DB::statement('ALTER TABLE `throttle` MODIFY `user_id` INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL;');
}
```

One note is that since you are converting between nullable and not nullable, you'll need to make sure you clean up data before/after your migration. So do that in your migration script both ways:

```
function up()
{
    DB::statement('ALTER TABLE `throttle` MODIFY `user_id` INTEGER UNSIGNED NULL;');
    DB::statement('UPDATE `throttle` SET `user_id` = NULL WHERE `user_id` = 0;');
}

function down()
{
    DB::statement('UPDATE `throttle` SET `user_id` = 0 WHERE `user_id` IS NULL;');
    DB::statement('ALTER TABLE `throttle` MODIFY `user_id` INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL;');
}
```

Comment: For Laravel 4, replace `query` by `statement`

Comment: Thanks @Razor. Updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: In the `down` function in the second code block, the SQL statement should end with `NOT NULL`. (The `down` function in the third example is correct.)

Answer (score 57):

He're the full migration for **Laravel 5**:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->unsignedInteger('user_id')->nullable()->change();
    });
}

public function down()
{
    Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->unsignedInteger('user_id')->nullable(false)->change();
    });
}
```

The point is, you can remove `nullable` by passing `false` as an argument.

Answer (score 30):

Adding to [Dmitri Chebotarev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5227177/dmitri-chebotarev)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32568625/6045800), as for Laravel 5+.

After requiring the **doctrine/dbal** package:

```
composer require doctrine/dbal
```

You can then make a migration with nullable columns, like so:

```php
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        // change() tells the Schema builder that we are altering a table
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->nullable()->change();
    });
}
```

To revert the operation, do:

```php
public function down()
{
    /* turn off foreign key checks for a moment */
    DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0');
    /* set null values to 0 first */
    DB::statement('UPDATE `users` SET `user_id` = 0 WHERE `user_id` IS NULL;');
    /* alter table */
    DB::statement('ALTER TABLE `users` MODIFY `user_id` INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL;');
    /* finally turn foreign key checks back on */
    DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1');
}
```

Answer (score 16):

If you happens to change the columns and stumbled on

```
'Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOMySql\Driver' not found
```

then just install

`composer require doctrine/dbal`

Comment: This bit me so I went ahead and made the exception / solution easier to follow: https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/10002

Answer (score 11):

I had to use `nullable(true)`

```
Schema::table('users', function($table)
{
    $table->string('name', 50)->nullable(true)->change();
});
```

Answer (score 8):

#### Install Composer Package:

```
composer require doctrine/dbal
```

After successfully install composer package we can change data type and change column name using migration command.

Syntax:

```
php artisan make:migration alter_table_[table_name]_change_[column_name] --table=[table_name]
```

Example:

```
php artisan make:migration alter_table_sessions_change_user_id --table=sessions

<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class AlterTableSessionsChangeUserId extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('sessions', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->nullable()->change();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('sessions', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->dropColumn('user_id');
        });
    }
}
```

And run: `php artisan migrate`

#### OR

Or table refresh to change column name. not use `change` method.

```
Schema::create('throttle', function(Blueprint $table)
{
    $table->increments('id');
    # old code
    $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
    # new code
    $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
}
```

**Note:** Below command to clear data from table.

```
php artisan migrate:refresh --path=/database/migrations/2021_09_31_050851_create_throttle_table.php
```

Answer (score 3):

Adding to Dmitri Chebotarev Answer,

If you want to alter multiple columns at a time , you can do it like below

```
DB::statement('
     ALTER TABLE `events` 
            MODIFY `event_date` DATE NOT NULL,
            MODIFY `event_start_time` TIME NOT NULL,
            MODIFY `event_end_time` TIME NOT NULL;
');
```

Answer (score 2):

Try it:

```
$table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
```

Comment: It doesn't alter existing column

Comment: you forgot `->change` at the end and to mention it Laravel 5+ only

Comment: You need to require `composer require doctrine/dbal`

Answer (score 2):

For Laravel 4.2, Unnawut's answer above is the best one. But if you are using table prefix, then you need to alter your code a little.

```
function up()
{
    $table_prefix = DB::getTablePrefix();
    DB::statement('ALTER TABLE `' . $table_prefix . 'throttle` MODIFY `user_id` INTEGER UNSIGNED NULL;');
}
```

And to make sure you can still rollback your migration, we'll do the `down()` as well.

```
function down()
{
    $table_prefix = DB::getTablePrefix();
    DB::statement('ALTER TABLE `' . $table_prefix . 'throttle` MODIFY `user_id` INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL;');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you need first install doctrine/dbal package.

```
composer require doctrine/dbal
```

and then use change() method
for example:

```
Schema::table('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id')->nullable()->change();
});
```