# Change tables structures with migration without losing data?

Tags: laravel, migration

I have read several threads about this but still not exactly my problem.
So in the `users` table I have a column called `role`, which is enum type and has two available values: 1 and 2. I set 2 as the default one. Now I want to change it to 1, for example. I created a new migration, ran `php artisan migrate` and encounter this error:

```
[Illuminate\DatabaseQueryException]                                           

SQLSTATE[42S21]: Column already exists: 1060 Duplicate column name 'role' (SQL: alter table `u  
  sers` add `role` enum('1', '2') not null default '1')                                                     
[PDOException]                                                             
  SQLSTATE[42S21]: Column already exists: 1060 Duplicate column name 'role'
```

Here is code in my CreateUsersTable migration file:

```
$table->enum('role', ['1', '2'])->default('2');
```

And I did the same in the new UpdateUsersTable migration file:

```
$table->enum('role', ['1', '2'])->default('1');
```

And by the way I can not use `php artisan migrate:refresh` because it will delete all my data. Where am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

```
$table->enum('role', ['1', '2'])->default('1')->change();
```

Comment: tried this and it required me to install doctrine/dbal.

Comment: but after installing it said that "Unknown database type enum requested, Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\MySQL57Platform may not support   
  it."

Comment: Yep, I missed it during answering. There is a problem with `enum` type in laravel. Take a look to this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/40176304/5130217.  Possible it's more correct.

Comment: I'm messing things up. Do you know how to uninstall doctrine/dbal? I've tried sudo apt-get remove php-doctrine-dbal but no result. Wrong package name, probably.

Comment: If it was installed with composer you need run `composer remove doctrine/dbal` for remove it

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class UpdateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        DB::statement('ALTER TABLE `users` MODIFY `role` DEFAULT 1;');
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        DB::statement('ALTER TABLE `users` MODIFY `role` DEFAULT 2;');
    }
}
```

Adapted from [this answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24425013/4480868)

Comment: @DuongNguyen
`ALTER TABLE users CHANGE COLUMN role role ENUM('1', '2') NOT NULL DEFAULT '1' ;`

Answer (score 1):

In order to do this you have to add `->nullable()` or `->default()` to every field you add to the migration file.

Answer (score 0):

1. create a new migration file

   ```
   php artisan make:migration add_role_to_users_table --table=users
   ```
2. open the created migration file (**database\migrations\2021_12_01_050851-add_role_tables.php**) and add below code.

   ```
    <?php
    use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
    use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

    class AddRoleToUsers extends Migration
    {
        /**
         * Run the migrations.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function up()
        {
            Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->enum('role', ['1', '2'])->default('1')->comment('1 - admin, 2 - normal'); //added
            });
        }

        /**
         * Reverse the migrations.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function down()
        {
            Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->dropColumn('role'); //added
            });
        }
    }
    ?>
   ```
3. Now migration refresh

   ```
   php artisan migrate:refresh --path=/database/migrations/2021_12_01_050851-add_role_tables.php
   ```