# How I can make Laravel migration change and make column nullable

Tags: laravel, database-design

I created a migration with post_id unsigned. How can I edit post_id in a new migration to also make it `nullable()`?

```
    Schema::create('throttle', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('post_id')->unsigned(); // this needs to also be nullable, how should the next migration be?
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel Migration Change to Make a Column Nullable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24419999/laravel-migration-change-to-make-a-column-nullable)

Answer (score 9):

Create migrate and add in your up function like this:

```
$table->integer('post_id')->nullable()->change();
```

Comment: Thank you too. Your answer also fixed my issue.

Answer (score -4):

```
 php artisan migrate:rollback
```

change your migration

```
$table->integer('post_id')->nullable();
```

then

```
php artisan migrate
```

Comment: you can also set default value in nullable

Comment: I already did. I am new here. It is giving me error when i click on up arrow

Comment: there is a accepet sign please accpet

Comment: @KuldeepMishra Why you need accpet ?

Comment: @TruongDang because i have answered successfully.