# How to change database column 'null' to 'nullable' using laravel migration in mysql?

Tags: mysql, laravel, migration, alter-table

This is my vehicles table. I want to change my database structure by using a migration

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateVehiclesTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('vehicles', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('image')->nullable();
            $table->string('reg_no')->unique();
            $table->string('fuel_type');
            $table->string('capacity');
            $table->double('rate');
            $table->boolean('req_carrier');
            $table->date('service_date');
            $table->integer('service_freq_km');
            $table->integer('service_freq_months');
            $table->date('insurance_date');
            $table->integer('insurance_freq_months');
            $table->date('eco_date');
            $table->integer('eco_freq_months');
            $table->date('licence_date');
            $table->integer('licence_freq_months');
            $table->integer('current_company');
            $table->string('status')->default("available");
            $table->timestampsTz();

        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('vehicles');
    }
}
```

I want to give nullable values to these columns.
1.service_date
2.service_freq_km
3.service_freq_months

How can I alter these columns as nullable in mysql?

Comment: you are already using `nullable()` for image column. use it for those column which you want to be null as default.

Comment: @zahidhasanemon yes When I first create this migration I added nullable(). Now I want it to add to those columns too.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel Migration Change to Make a Column Nullable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24419999/laravel-migration-change-to-make-a-column-nullable)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can read the docs about [`Modifying Columns`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/migrations#modifying-columns).

If you want these feature, you need to install this package first:

```sh
composer require doctrine/dbal
```

Then, you need to create another migration, for example:

**2019_10_24_xxxxxx_change_columns_to_nullable_in_vehicles.php**

```php
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class ChangeColumnsToNullableInVehicles extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('vehicles', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->date('service_date')->nullable()->change();
            $table->integer('service_freq_km')->nullable()->change();
            $table->integer('service_freq_months')->nullable()->change();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('vehicles', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->date('service_date')->nullable(false)->change();
            $table->integer('service_freq_km')->nullable(false)->change();
            $table->integer('service_freq_months')->nullable(false)->change();
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

install the package in order to update the tables `composer require doctrine/dbal`

Since you have migrated the migration files, you now need to create a new migration file using artisan command:

```
php artisan make:migration change_nullable_field_columns_to_vehicles_tables --table=vehicles
```

In newly created migration file, add the following codes

```
public function up() {
        Schema::table('vehicles', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->date('service_date')->nullable()->change();
            $table->integer('service_freq_km')->nullable()->change();
            $table->integer('service_freq_months')->nullable()->change();
        });
    }
```

*//For php artisan down*

```
public function down(){
            Schema::table('vehicles', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->date('service_date')->nullable(false)->change();
                $table->integer('service_freq_km')->nullable(false)->change();
                $table->integer('service_freq_months')->nullable(false)->change();
            });
}
```

Now you can execute migrate command

```
php artisan migrate
```

Comment: `composer require doctrine/dbal` installation of this package is required to complete your answer

Answer (score 0):

create new migration class for alter table and use this up function

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('vehicles', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->date('service_date')->nullable();
        $table->integer('service_freq_km')->nullable();
        $table->integer('service_freq_months')->nullable();

   });
}
```

Schema::table use for alter table and Schema::create is use for create new table

Comment: @Rasshid I have already migrated the migration. Now I want to change it as `$table->date('service_date')->nullable();` how can I alter the table?

Comment: to update  a table `composer require doctrine/dbal` this package is required

Answer (score 0):

You need to create new migration file that is name "2019_10_24_00000_update_vehicle_tables"

```
if(Schema::hasTable('vehicles')) {
    Schema::table('vehicles', function($table)
    {
        $table->date('service_date')->nullable();
        $table->integer('service_freq_km')->nullable();
        $table->integer('service_freq_months')->nullable();
    });
}
```

Comment: @alprnkesskekoglu should I write this inside the "up" function?

Comment: i forget it sorry... you need write inside the "up" function

Answer (score 0):

```
$table->string('first_name')->default('DEFAULT');
```

If the default value is supposed to be null, make it nullable instead.

```
$table->string('name')->nullable();

$table->string('name')->nullable()->default('NULL');

$table->string('name')->nullable()->default(NULL);

$table->string('name')->nullable()->default();
```