# if it is not filled in it will automatically be filled with the string "" or null

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I have an input form with the name `student_lastname[]`.

```
<div class="form-group col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-6 col-sm-6">
     <label for="inputLastName">Last Name </label>
     <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputLastName_1" name="student_lastname[]" placeholder="" >
</div>
```

If it is not filled in it will automatically be filled with the string `""` or null, and if the value is filled in, then send the filled value. How can I create such conditions?

Comment: set `student_lastname` nullable in database or `$table->string('student_lastname)->nullable();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new migration that sets your column values to be nullable, to do that, refer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24419999/laravel-migration-change-to-make-a-column-nullable). Then, in your controller, check whether the requested data is empty, if so, do not set any value to the field. It could look something like this (assuming the form makes a `POST` request):

```
// your code here
if(request('student_lastname[]')){
// set student last name
}
// if the field was left empty, student's last name will be null 
// rest of your code
```