# Changing a migration value in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I created a migration that had a nullable, but then I realized that it should be default 0. Is there a way to change that with another migration.

Here is my original migration

```
Schema::table('items', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('total')->nullable();
});
```

and this is the migration I'm trying to run

```
Schema::table('items', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('total')->default(0);
});
```

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#updating-column-attributes read the doc please

Comment: don't know if this is good practice but if your database is new and is not live then you can make changes to existing migration instead of making another migration just to modify a column attribute and run that migration as fresh, Assuming you have seeders set up, because you'll lose data on running fresh migrations.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Make column not nullable in a Laravel migration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14013832/make-column-not-nullable-in-a-laravel-migration)

Answer (score -1):

Reference Laravel 8.x documentation you can try this code to update column attributes

`Schema::table('items', function (Blueprint $table) { $table->unsignedBigInteger('total')->default(0)->change(); });`

Comment: I tried that and the items in my database was still null

Comment: can you please elaborate how you did it?

Comment: `$table->unsignedBigInteger('total')->default(0)->change();` and then run migrate

Comment: which version of laravel you are using?

Comment: have you added dependency?? 
`composer require doctrine/dbal`

Comment: I'm using version 8

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224771/discussion-between-waqar-akram-and-aurilie).

Comment: @Aurilie Just read the duplicate question and answer already posted above in comments.